# Missing Fedex cloud print on OnePlus w/ Androind 4.4.4 / T-Mobile

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, printing

On my moto x 1st gen on T-Mobile I had an option when printing to print to a FedEx office. I'd get emailed a retrieval code to use at the store. On my oneplus I only have a save as PDF option in the print list (Google drive PDF viewer). I installed the FedEx app but that didn't add the printing option for FedEx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a very similar issue.  I don't use Chrome on the desktop (Firefox) but I don't think that is relevant.  I am also using Nexus 5 with Android 5.0.1.  On my PC on Firefox I could see the Fedex printer listed along side the Google Drive printer but on my Nexus I could only see the Google Drive printer.  I fiddled with this for a while but I eventually got it to work.  I'm not totally sure what I did that fixed it but this what I tried:

- Visited https://www.google.com/cloudprint/learn/ and clicked Try It Now
- Select Print to Fedex Office and clicked the checkbox to agree to the terms (this only showed up once and maybe this was blocking it from showing up on Android?)
- I didn't bother trying to print a test page to Fedex but I did go back print a test page using the Save to Google Drive option (again not sure if this was needed)
- I verified that it showed up properly in my drive account
- Finally I went back to my phone: Settings -> Printing -> Cloud Print.  Still only Google Drive printer listed (damn!).
- But then I hit the back button and tapped Cloud Print once again (hey why not?) and all of a sudden the FedEx Office printer was listed!

So I'm not really sure what the deal is with this (definitely still beta I guess).  I think either agreeing to the terms on the PC and/or printing a test page kind of forced a refresh of cloud print settings down to my phone.  I wonder if clearing the data of the cloud print app would have a similar effect?  Anyways, I hope this helps a future person that got here via Google like I did...

Comment: Yay!!! Its working now :) Not sure if everything else was needed but in settings > printing > cloud print, i have a little slider to enable/disable the service. Fedex and google drive showed up after I toggled it.

Answer (score 0):

Install [Google Cloud Print](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.cloudprint&hl=en) from google play store. Then if I log in to the Cloud Print on my computer I see that I can print to the Fedex Office. I have not tried to print from my device, but I would assume I could pick this as a printer as well.

[image]

[Fedex Information on Cloud Printing](http://www.fedex.com/us/office/cloud-printing.html)
Print to our self-service printers using your mobile device.

- Send your print job to FedEx Office from your smartphone, tablet, PC, Mac® or other web-connected device using Google Cloud Print`TM`, HP® ePrint or Breezy® or Canon® Forms & Print Services.
- Receive a unique retrieval code that can be used in any of our convenient locations.
- Enter your unique retrieval code. (Access by clicking on the link within your confirmation email or logging into Google Cloud Print and selecting your print job.)

Comment: Its already installed, ill try reinstalling...

Comment: If you log in to google cloud print from the browser/pc, do you see fedex as an options?

Comment: Reinstalling Google cloud print didn't help, its also missing from print options in chrome from my oneplus, ill check chrome desktop later.

Comment: Yep sure do have Print to FedEx office as an option when signed into Chrome desktop.